# fetch-mock: No fallback response defined for POST

Tags: javascript, api, unit-testing, jestjs, fetch-mock

All my **GET** requests are going through but **POST** ones fail. This happens when I update `fetch-mock` from `7.3.0` to `7.3.1` or **later**.

**console.warn** `Unmatched POST to url`

**Error** `fetch-mock: No fallback response defined for POST to url`

**http.js**

```
export const get = (url) => {
  const options = {
    method: 'GET',
    credentials: 'same-origin'
  };

  return fetch(url, options).then(handleJsonResponse);
};

export const post = (url, body) => {
  const headers = {
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'pragma': 'no-cache',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache'
  };

  return fetch(url, {
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    method: 'POST',
    cache: 'no-cache',
    body: JSON.stringify(body),
    headers
  }).then(handleJsonResponse);
};
```

**http.spec.js**

```
const url = '/path/to/url'

describe('get', () => {
    it('makes a GET request', async () => {
      fetchMock.mock({
        name: 'route',
        matcher: url,
        method: 'GET',
        credentials: 'same-origin',
        response: {
          status: 200,
          body: []
        }
      });

      const response = await get(url);

      expect(fetchMock.called()).toEqual(true);
      expect(fetchMock.calls().length).toEqual(1);
      expect(fetchMock.calls('route').length).toEqual(1);
      expect(response).toEqual([]);
    });
  });

  describe('post', () => {
    const requestBody = {request: 'request'};

    it('makes a POST request', async () => {
      fetchMock.mock({
        name: 'route',
        matcher: url,
        method: 'POST',
        credentials: 'same-origin',
        cache: 'no-cache',
        body: JSON.stringify(requestBody),
        headers: {
          'content-type': 'application/json',
          'pragma': 'no-cache',
          'cache-control': 'no-cache'
        },
        response: {
          status: 200,
          body: []
        }
      });

      const response = await post(url, requestBody);

      expect(fetchMock.called()).toEqual(true);
      expect(fetchMock.calls().length).toEqual(1);
      expect(fetchMock.calls('route').length).toEqual(1);
      expect(fetchMock.lastOptions().headers).toEqual({
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        'pragma': 'no-cache',
        'cache-control': 'no-cache'
      });
      expect(response).toEqual([]);
    });
  });
```

Any thoughts on what's causing this? Is there a way to get more meaningful logs to help with debugging this?

I would rather not go the alternative path of trying **nock** or **jest-fetch-mock**.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Alright, after hours of digging into the library itself I have found out where the issue was.

In my code (and the snippet above) I am **stringifying** the body `JSON.stringify(body)`. The library's `generate-matcher.js` is **parsing** it `JSON.parse(body)` and then compares the two - the point which was causing the failure. I am now just sending it as the raw object.

Comment: Can you share the updated code? I am facing a similar issue.

Comment: any comments on updated code?

Answer (score 5):

In case anyone else ends up here in the future, I had the same error accompanied with `fetch-mock unmatched get`.

I saw the response to [this issue filed to fetch-mock](https://github.com/wheresrhys/fetch-mock/issues/299) which prompted me to double check my expected values and mocked values.

It turns out my problem was exactly as the error described, where the mock route I was expecting and the actual route that was being called were mismatched because of a typo.

Comment: extra slash got me. Thanks!